# grep to IP address when IP address in parameter

Tags: linux, perl, grep, ksh

I need to grep to  IP address ( as the following example )
, I use ksh script ,

```
    #  ifconfig -a |  /usr/xpg4/bin/grep   "100\.106\.2\.120 "
    inet 100.106.2.120 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 100.106.2.255
```

but how to grep IP address from parameter  ( IP_ADDRESS ) ?

- Remark - IP address could be any IP

how to add the back slash in this case

IP_ADDRESS=192.2.34.2 , or IP_ADDRESS=192.2.34.20 ... etc

```
    #  ifconfig -a |  /usr/xpg4/bin/grep   "$IP_ADDRESS "
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the bash shell you can Use parameter expansion:

```
ifconfig -a | /usr/xpg4/bin/grep "${IP_ADDRESS//./\\.}"
```

If your shell doesn't support this type of parameter expansion, you could use shell expansion instead, e.g. with sed:

```
ifconfig -a | /usr/xpg4/bin/grep `echo $IP_ADDRESS | sed 's/\./\\./g'`
```

or perl:

```
ifconfig -a | /usr/xpg4/bin/grep `echo $IP_ADDRESS | perl -pne 's/\./\\./g'`
```

Comment: I use the ksh shell not the bash shell

Comment: @yael: many versions of ksh also support this type of parameter expansion.

Comment: my ksh not support it  - # ifconfig -a | /usr/xpg4/bin/grep "${IP_ADDRESS//./\\.}"
ksh: "${IP_ADDRESS//./\\.}": bad substitution

Comment: @yael: alternatively you could use shell expansion, see edit.